# using Unicode(Farsi) Character in SharePoint Management Shell

Tags: powershell

I want to update user display name in SharePoint using SharePoint management shell, the problem is all Unicode character I am using is displayed as "?" mark.

How Can I Use Farsi in SharePoint PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to change the language pack.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.language%28v=office.14%29.aspx

As a starting point followed by:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splocale.lcid(v=office.14).aspx

The LCID of farsi is under "persian" on the list: 1065

Once changed, the language packs should recognise the farsi characters.